# Преобразования строки в массив по цифрам в строке

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Работаю в Laravel V5.5. Есть строка вида `'a0';'b0.3';'abc2.2'; 'abcde5'` и т.д., как разбить строку на массив?

Количество символов и цифр не известно.

`['a'=>[0=>XXX]];['b'=>[0=>[3=>XXX]]];['abc'=>[2=>[2=>XXX]]];['abcde5'=>[2=>XXX]]`

Comment: Вопрос, вероятно, будет закрыт, так как на *Stack Overflow **на русском*** вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: Чем обусловлена такая ассоциативная вложенность? Если вы напишите цель решения задачи будет более понятно.

Comment: `'abcde'=>[5=>XXX]` судя по всему должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

проверок на валидность нет, то есть мы считаем, что каждый элемент содержит одну или более букву в начале и одну цифру или цифры разделенные точками, без лишних точек 
лишние пробелы убираем

```
<?php

$longString = "'a0';'b0.3';'abc2.2'; 'abcde5'";

function convertLongString($string, $defaultValue)
{
    //приведение исходной строки к массиву ['a0', 'b0.3', 'abc2.2']
    $string = str_replace(["'", " "], '', $string);
    $arr = explode(';', $string);

    $result = [];    
    foreach ($arr as $el) {
        $result[] = convertString($el, $defaultValue);
    }
    return $result;
}

// превращение строки b0.3 в матрешку массивов
function convertString ($string, $defaultValue)
{
    preg_match('/([a-z]+)([0-9.]*)/', $string, $search);
    $firstKey = $search[1];
    $array = explode('.', $search[2]);
    return [$firstKey => rec($array, $defaultValue)];
}

function rec(array $array, $defaultValue)
{
    if (!$array) {
        return $defaultValue;
    } 
    $el = array_shift($array);
    return [$el => rec($array, $defaultValue)];
}


print_r(convertLongString($longString, 'XXX'));
```

места типа

```
$firstKey = $search[1];
$array = explode('.', $search[2]);
return [$firstKey => rec($array, $defaultValue)];
```

не написаны в одну строчку

```
return [$search[1],  rec(explode('.', $search[2]), $defaultValue)];
```

для читаемости кода